# Flash drag and drop uploader?

Tags: java, flash, drag-and-drop, applet

I've seen this done with a signed Java Applet, but is it possible with Flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the browser, no. You can have the user browse for a file but no drag and drop.

A desktop AIR application can do this though and it can be installed through a special Flash movie referred to as an installer badge that lives on a web page like any other Flash movie.